# Author Permissions on WordPress Blog

Tags: plugins

I'm looking for a suggestion on how to set up the user permissions on wordpress plugin. For Example: I've Contact Form 7 plugin, when a author signing in to his account, he can see the plugin and upon clicking on it he can easily see the shortcodes. I want all author have access just the "Posts" item from wordpress admin panel (left navigation), so that they can just post article or nothing else.

Is it possible? How can i do that? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this plugin? It seems to be what you need.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin ==> https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor
With that you'll create a custom role with custom permission or change the existant

Enjoy ;)